# iTunes Connect Does my Hybrid app Contain Encryption (Apple Export Compliance)?

Tags: ios, encryption, https, uiwebview, app-store-connect

Im about to release a hybrid app that i have built for iOS and want to know if it "contains encryption" from the point of view of apples export compliance.

Im using multiple UIWebView's to open certain URL's (https://linkName) and for authentication as well. The app does not have a REST API, just web views that load a web page based on the URL. I also use flurry and their iOS SDK for analytics.

Does this mean that it falls under the "Contains Encryption" for apple? Or is it ok to check no for this and submit to the app store.